# navigation does not work when imported - React native

Tags: react-native

When I use props.navigation.navigate("example"), it works normally. But if I import the component on another page it doesn't work anymore, props returns an empty object.

**Works Fine:**

```
const Menu = props =>{
console.log(props)
return(
       
    <View style={styles.menuStyle}>

        <TouchableOpacity  style={styles.topicDiv} onPress={() =>props.navigation.navigate("Ads")}>
        <View>
           
            <Image style={styles.topicStyle} source={require ("../assets/security-camera.png")}/>
            <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Câmeras</Text>
            <Text style={styles.subTextStyle}>Veja como está a praia ao vivo </Text>
```

**If i try import Menu, navigation does not work:**

```
  import React from "react";
import { View } from "react-native";
import Menu from "./menu";

const Supermenu = () =>{
    return(
        <View>

           <Menu></Menu> 
           
        </View>
    )
}

export default Supermenu
```

Comment: Could you add the code you have tried to use?

Comment: add the related code snippet.  your problem might be with passing the props with on parent and children component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `<Menu>` inside of another component like `<Supermenu>`, React Navigation has no way to pass its `navigation` property in there. It only happens automatically if a component is a direct child of a screen (or its `component` property).

To have `navigation` available in `Menu` regardless of its position in the hierarchy, as long as it's a child of `<NavigationContainer>`, the best way is to make use of the `useNavigation` hook:

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/core';

const Menu = props =>{
    const navigation = useNavigation();

    return (
        <View style={styles.menuStyle}>
             <TouchableOpacity style={styles.topicDiv} onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Ads")}>
...
```

See [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/connecting-navigation-prop/) for more detail.

If you are on an older version, there was also a [HOC `withNavigation`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/with-navigation/) that you could use.

You could also do the same in `Supermenu` and then pass `navigation` down manually.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

use `import {userNavigation} from '@react-navigation/core'` instead of props navigate or you can add navigation props to the Menu component.